# Apply classes to selected XHTML elements based on content

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish to take an XHTML source document (e.g. demo.in.xhtml below) and add `class` attributes to every `td` element whose content is one of the following six strings: `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`, `C1`, or `C2`. The corresponding classes will be `mytable-a1`, `mytable-a2`, `mytable-b1`, `mytable-b2`, `mytable-c1`, `mytable-c2`. Any other `td` elements in the source document should be kept as they are.

demo.xsl performs this as desired, but is not DRY: it uses a six-line `xsl:template` element per `class` attribute. How can I refactor this so as to remove the repetition, or generally make demo.xsl more concise and readable?

I am using the following command on Debian Jessie GNU/Linux to perform the transformation:

```
saxonb-xslt -s:demo.in.xhtml -xsl:demo.xsl -o:demo.out.xhtml
```

### demo.in.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>C2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

### demo.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!--
    Inspiration
    URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2973585
    Author: Mads Hansen
    License: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
    -->

    <!--Custom behavior for matched nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="//td[.='A1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-a1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td[.='A2']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-a2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td[.='B1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-b1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td[.='B2']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-b2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td[.='C1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-c1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td[.='C2']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mytable-c2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Identity template (copies input into output) -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create the class based on the value of the `td`.

**Input** (I added a `td` that should not be modified by the stylesheet.)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="mytable">
            <tr>
                <td>A1</td>
                <td>A2</td>
                <td>B1</td>
                <td>B2</td>
                <td>C1</td>
                <td>C2</td>
                <td>ignore me</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="tds" select="('A2','B1','B2','C1','C2')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td[normalize-space()=$tds]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="class" 
        select="concat('mytable-',lower-case(normalize-space()))"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class="mytable">
         <tr>
            <td class="foo">A1</td>
            <td class="mytable-a2">A2</td>
            <td class="mytable-b1">B1</td>
            <td class="mytable-b2">B2</td>
            <td class="mytable-c1">C1</td>
            <td class="mytable-c2">C2</td>
            <td>ignore me</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**

1. In my `match`, I didn't use the `//` abbreviated syntax (`match="//td"`); I just used `match="td"`.
2. I used `xsl:param` instead of using the sequence `('A2','B1','B2','C1','C2')` directly in the match so that it could be passed in at runtime. This would allow you to change which `td` elements were modified without changing the actual code.
3. Try to use a select attribute on `xsl:attribute`, even when outputting plain text (`<xsl:attribute name="class" select="'mytable-c2'"/>`). This prevents creating unnecessary RTF's (result tree fragments).
4. I use `normalize-space()` when creating the class to strip any leading/trailing whitespace in the text() node.
5. After creating the `class` attribute, we do an `xsl:apply-templates` on `@*`. If there is an existing class attribute, it will overwrite what we just created. If this is a possibility, I'd do an `xsl:apply-templates` on `@*`, then create the new class attribute (overwrites the existing class or you can concat the new and old), and then finally do the `xsl:apply-templates` on `node()`.